# Reactjs hooks state not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have this checkbox components

```
 import styled from 'styled-components'

import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import React from 'react'

const CheckboxContainer = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
`

const Icon = styled.svg`
  fill: none;
  stroke: #45cc8a;
  stroke-width: 2px;
`

const HiddenCheckbox = styled.input.attrs({ type: 'checkbox' })`
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  clippath: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
`

const StyledCheckbox = styled.div`
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 150ms;
  margin-top: 10px;

  ${Icon}:checked {
    visibility: ${({ checked }) => (checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden')};
  }
`

const Checkbox = ({ className, checked, ...props }) => (
  <CheckboxContainer className={className}>
    <HiddenCheckbox checked={checked} {...props} />
    <StyledCheckbox checked={checked}>
      <Icon viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <polyline points="20 6 9 17 4 12" />
      </Icon>
    </StyledCheckbox>
  </CheckboxContainer>
)

Checkbox.propTypes = {
  checked: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default Checkbox
```

I want to check and uncheck it as the following code shows.

I use this checkbox component in another,But the problem is the stroke is not being disabled or enabled,it is always visible,any suggestions?

```
 const SignUp = ({ title }) => {
  const [checked, SetChecked] = React.useState(false)

  const handleCheckboxChange = event => {
    SetChecked(event.target.checked)
  }

               return   <Checkbox checked={checked} onChange={handleCheckboxChange} />

  }
```

Any suggestions please? I encountered this problem today and I dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the `${Icon}:checked`, you making it visible for every case whether is checked or not, please remove the `:checked` and it will work.

Comment: @NikaRoffy here is a sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-waterfall-14qvm?file=/src/index.js the only thing I changed is `:checked`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that although your component accepts a prop called `checked`, input's do not. To define whether an input of type checkbox is checked, it takes the prop `value`.

Change you handler to

```
  const handleCheckboxChange = event => {
    SetChecked(!event.target.value)
  }
```

and your component to this

```
<HiddenCheckbox value={checked} {...props} />
```

Comment: Which part says props not defined, can you give a bit more detail

Comment: its says here `<HiddenCheckbox value={checked} {...props} />`  ..props -> is not defined

Comment: this appears in the components in which i m importing checkbox

Comment: I mean to make to change in your `Checkbox` component. Since you have this line, `const Checkbox = ({ className, checked, ...props }) => (` the value `props` should be defined